# How do I change font size in context menu in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, fonts, theme

I'm using `X-Arc-Darker` theme for GNOME 3. I looked for many options in `~/.themes/X-Arc-Darker/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` but I could not find any that allows changing font size in menus and in context menu? Is it possible? If so, how do I do that?

**Menu font:**
[image]

**Context menu font:**

[image]

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873863/how-to-reduce-context-menu-size-in-gnome)

Comment: on a side note, what terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @joaocandre It is GNOME Terminal with zsh as shell.